# How to re-draw a particular portion of canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating an `HTML 5` game using the `<canvas>` and `JavaScript`.

In my canvas I'm loading high resolution images. In each Minute there will come some objects to this canvas. If user clicks on it. It'll be removed from the screen.

My issue:

I'm using `clearRect()` function for clearing the canvas. And again re-draws all images. Is it necessary that each time I re-draw the entire content ? Is there any option to re-draw that particular area ?

When I used the `clearRect()` to clear the exact area of that object. The background image also got removed. Is there any way to save the particular portion of background image and draw that portion with this saved image ? (Because my objects are moving on the canvas, I need to retreive the image data dynamically)

I'm new to WebTechnology and HTML 5. So please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you build up the canvas layers and then just clear the specified layer so the background that doesn't need clearing put on one layer and then the part that does draw on another and just use the clearRect on that layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few canvas layer libraries that adds support for the layers:

- [CanvasLayers](https://bitbucket.org/ant512/canvaslayers/wiki/Home)
- [CanvasStack](http://arc.id.au/CanvasLayers.html)

Answer (score 2):

Think of the canvas as a painting, it is not possible to remove a "layer" of content once it has been applied. You can specify a portion of the canvas to clear using `clearRect(x,y,height,width)`, but you will always need to redraw the background of what you deleted. The `drawImage()` function takes arguments to draw a specific portion of an image in a specific location, but perhaps more along the lines of what you are looking to use is imageData.

I suggest you do some reading up on the canvas here [Mozilla Dev Network: Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas)

Comment: For saving the background image or multiple images you could also use multiple canvas elements.